# Where is the redirection configured?

Tags: debian, .htaccess, php-fpm

I have a redirection but I don't know where it is activated?

I have installed a PHP application called GARRADIN.
There is an .htaccess containing this line:

```
RewriteRule admin/plugin/(.*?)/(.*) /admin/plugin.php?_p=$1&_u=$2 [QSA,L]
```

This redirection works. plugin.php is called but parameters $1 and $2 are empty. $_GET['_p'] returns nothing into the script.

To understand why parameters are not transmitted, I have tried to modify .htaccess but whatever I do, it is not taken into account. It seems that this redirection is configured somewhere else?

What I did:
- I have inserted an error into .htaccess, and I obtain a server error => OK, .htaccess is taken into account.
- I modified the line to redirect to XXXXplugin.php but plugin.php is still called.
- renamed .htaccess to BAK.htaccess => redirection is still working!
- I have reset the browser cache, used another browser => same redirection.

so WHERE the redirection is configured?

THX for you help.

Complete .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule admin/plugin/(.*?)/(.*) /admin/XXXXXXXXXXXXplugin.php?_p=$1&_u=$2 [QSA,L]
    RewriteRule f/([\d\w]+)/(.*) /file.php?id=$1&file=$2 [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .* /index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is there a `.htaccess` in the admin directory or do you have any rules in the Server config files?

Comment: YES there is an .htaccess also in www/admin but it only contains: ErrorDocument 404 "<h1>Erreur 404</h1><h2>Page non trouv&eacute;e</h2><p><a href=../>Retour</a></p>"

Answer (score 2):

@MrWhite took me to the right direction. I had to deactivate MultiViews, not at the top of the .htaccess (which leads to a server error) but into the virtual host configuration file, and into a  section.

```
<Directory /home/gestion_o2form/public_html/www>
    Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews <= HERE
    allow from all
    AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,-MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Require all granted
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</Directory>
```

And IT WORK!

THANKS to all especially @MrWhite

Comment: It didn't work in `.htaccess` because you have an erroneous `-` in the `AllowOverride` directive. It should be `...,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIf...` (no hyphen before `MultiViews` here). (It looks like you had tried to disable `MultiViews`, but in the wrong place?) However, since you have access to the vHost config, it's preferable to disable this here anyway. Thanks for the feedback, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour you are seeing is indicative of having `MultiViews` (part of mod_negotiation) enabled in your server config (it is *not* enabled by default).

Since `/admin` is a physical directory and `plugin` corresponds to a file basename in that directory, mod_negotiation searches for a suitable response by testing various file extensions. In this case it will issue an internal subrequest for `/admin/plugin.php` - without any query parameters. This happens *before* mod_rewrite, hence why your updated directive does not appear to do anything.

You need to disable `MultiViews`.

At the top of your `.htaccess` file add the following:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

---

> This redirection works.

This is more commonly called an *internal rewrite*. A "redirect" implies an *external redirect*.

Note that the regex `admin/plugin/(.*?)/(.*)` potentially matches more than is probably intended, as you are missing a start-of-string anchor (`^`). So it would also match something like `/foobaradmin/plugin//`.

Comment: I had a Multiviews option activated into the virtual host conf file. Following your suggestion, I have deactivate it: AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,-MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

Comment: I have put **-MultiViews** I'am not sure it works? anyway this does not work.

Comment: the I have put **Options -MultiViews** at the top of .htaccess. It goes to an internal server error.

Comment: Ah yes, that's the wrong place. The `AllowOverride` directive tells Apache what directives can be overridden in `.htaccess`. Changing `MultiViews` to `-MultiViews` here is not valid (the same as if you'd removed `MultiViews` altogether) and essentially means that `MultiViews` cannot be overridden in `.htaccess` - hence the 500 error when trying to do so. You need to use the `Options` directive (in `.htaccess` or server config), as you have done.